# Am I Querying and Subclassing Correctly?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Below is my code that I am using to query for an object from Parse:

```
func findEmployeeForLoggedInUser(completion: (array: [AnyObject], error: String?) -> Void) {
    var query = PFQuery(className: "Employee")
    query.whereKey("employerId", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (results, error) -> Void in

        println(results)

        var employeeArray = results


        if let error = error {
            let errorString = error.userInfo?["error"] as? String
            if let objects = employeeArray {
                completion(array: objects, error: errorString)
            } else {
                completion(array: [], error: errorString)
            }
        } else {
            completion(array: employeeArray!, error: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the code where the subclass of PFObject was declared:

```
class PFEmployee: PFObject, PFSubclassing {

override class func initialize() {
    self.registerSubclass()
}
class func parseClassName() -> String {
    return "Employee"
}

@NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var jobDesc: String
    @NSManaged var numberOfPoints: Int
    @NSManaged var education: String
    @NSManaged var birthday: String
    @NSManaged var employerId: String
    @NSManaged var profilePicture: PFFile?
    @NSManaged var email: String
    @NSManaged var commentary: String
}
```

My app is crashing, and I suspect it has something to do with this. Am I doing all of this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Use this crash free code...

```
var stuffarray = [String]()

        var query = PFQuery(className:"ClassName")

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {
                // The find succeeded.
                println("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) scores.")
                // Do something with the found objects
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    for object in objects {

                        stuffarray.append(object.valueForKey("Column")! as! String)



                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.alert("\(stuffarray)", Message: "")
            }
        }
```